# false transaction mined but execution failed - remix.ethereum

Tags: contract-development, metamask, nft, erc-721, polygon

When I try to deploy a contract on remix.ethereum using Metamask on polygon network transaction couldn't complete & below error message shown after complete transaction. This is a smart contract(ERC 721) to deploy.
false transaction mined but execution failed

Comment: Hi shaun! Welcome to Ethereum Stackexchange! Can you share the contract? Do you have an screenshot of the error?

Comment: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/users/2124/ismael i used this contract & change only public cost & paused = true https://github.com/HashLips/solidity_smart_contracts/blob/main/contracts/NFT/NFT.sol i used metamask with polygon

Comment: this error message is shown when i tryto transact- Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?
Internal JSON-RPC error. { "code": -32000, "message": "execution reverted" }

Comment: I compiled and deployed the contract on mumbai testnet using remix (injected web3) on Firefox  and it did work as expected without warning, without any error.